# Oracle 11gR2 on Aix listner will not start

Tags: oracle, listener, aix

I have created a new Oracle instance on the Aix server.  Database is running fine, but my listener would not start.  I got the following errors in the listener log:

```
<msg time='2012-09-26T17:33:17.304-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='xxxxx111'
 host_addr='000.00.0.111'>
 <txt>TNS-12546: TNS:permission denied
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00516: Permission denied
   IBM/AIX RISC System/6000 Error: 2: No such file or directory
 </txt>
</msg>
```

When I tried to start the listener, i got the following error:

```
lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 26-SEP-2012 17:38:17

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /oracle/QI1/112_64/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
System parameter file is /oracle/QI1/112_64/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /oracle/QI1/saptrace/diag/tnslsnr/xxxxxx/listener/alert/log.xml
Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxxxxx.na.xxxxx.com)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12542: TNS:address already in use
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00512: Address already in use
   IBM/AIX RISC System/6000 Error: 67: Address already in use

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Following @dave's answer, I checked the `sqlnet.ora` file, and the error was in the parameter:

```
TCP.VALIDNODE_CHECKING = YES
```

After commenting out the line, the listener starts

```
#TCP.VALIDNODE_CHECKING = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the ip address SQLnet file was incorrect.  After fixing the ip address,the listener was able to start.